# how much openvz burstable memory can be used

Tags: memory, vps, openvz

I want to buy a VPS having openvz virtualization.

Now the applications that i m currently hosting( glassfish, mysql, mail) requires around 600~800 MB of RAM.

Would I be able to run my applications if I go for 512 MB of ram and 512 MB burstable ram?

Add on to that i think there would 1GB swap.

thanks

Comment: For a rented VPS, I fail to understand why **anyone** would choose a provider that uses OpenVZ. There are so many limitations, gotchas, etc. with OpenVZ that are **completely** absent with other technologies like Xen and KVM.

Comment: It's super cheap.  Sometimes you care about that more than performance :)

Comment: @EEAA kvm ram would not be the total ram as memory would be consumed by the os also. I think xen is better than kvm and openVZ. So would my above  config work  with 512mb xen vps?

Comment: OpenVZ doesn't support swap. So what add on are you talking about?

Comment: Not to mention that Java doesn't like OpenVZ very much...

Comment: @MichaelHampton please elaborate why so, particularity why so with java? Any leads? Not openVZ then Xen or KVM?

Answer (score 1):

"Burstable" means that it's available if there's extra RAM on the host, but it's not promised to your VM. It's not recommended to run permanently into your "burst" RAM as this could result in instability if the host needs that RAM for some reason.

Swap is *very bad* for performance and it should ideally not be used. It's there in case your server receives a spike in traffic so that the OS can remain functional.